# Velocity of a falling body as a function of time AND mass

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, mass, acceleration, free-fall

I'm working on a small java program, and I was wondering if there was an equation to calculate the *approximate* velocity of a falling body, in function to its mass $M$ and the time $t$ since the beginning of the fall (example; Body $A$ of a mass of *57kg* has a velocity of $y$ after *11 seconds* of fall) I googled it and the only equations I found were either in function of time or mass, but never both. Sorry if this comes out as a rudimentary question, I'm a computer science student, my last physics course was in high school.

Comment: The velocity of a falling body doesn't have anything to do with its mass (as long as it's falling a short distance in a vacuum towards something that's much bigger). The expression is $v=-gt$, where $g$ is the gravitational acceleration (9.8 m/s^2 here on Earth).

Comment: So a pencil would fall at the same speed as a 18-ton truck?

Comment: In a vacuum, yes. Here's some experimental evidence: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=frZ9dN_ATew

Comment: Wow, that's super interesting. Thanks for the info!

Comment: @probably_someone In a practical context though, I assume the falling body would eventually reach a maximum velocity, no? I thought such a function would be logarithmic with an asymptote near the maximum value, while with v = -gt, as _t_ approaches infinity, so does _|v|_

Comment: @Simon Besozzi the simplest thing you could perhaps do to model the motion on a more practical level would be to introduce a damping term $-bv$. Already you will see an asymptotic velocity here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Equation for a falling body including terminal velocity](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/261901).

Comment: [I think this is relevant.](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/1019/common-false-beliefs-in-physics/1027#1027) Somehow.

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/11321/2451 and links therein.

Comment: To reopen this post (v3), mention IN THE POST if air resistance should be taken into account, and if yes, preferably mention how air resistance should be modelled.

Answer (score 0):

Gravitational field strength on earth is 9.8m/s^2 so I think you can just rearrange the acceleration equation which is a = ∆v/t 
So 9.8 = ∆v/11 so ∆v=9.8*11. Velocity in a falling object isn't affected by its mass, hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest thing you could perhaps do to model the motion on a more practical level would be to introduce a damping term $−bv$. Already you will see an asymptotic velocity here and an explicit dependence of $v$ on $m$ and $t$, as one would expect.

So, instead of solving $m \dot{v} = mg$ in vacua solve $$m \dot{v} = mg - bv,$$ a step up in description accounting for resistive forces.  You will find something like $$v = \frac{mg}{b} \left(1 - \exp(-bt/m) \right)$$ with asymptote $mg/b$ as $t$ gets large.

Depending on the details of the object, it may be preferable to describe the damping instead with a $-bv^2$ dependence etc

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you are in earths gravitational field, an equation of time and mass will end with the mass cancelled, so it's irrelevant to the calculation.

Otherwise:
$$v_f=v_0+t*\frac{Gm_om}{r^2}$$ where $m_o$ is the mass of the planet or body you're on.